# Got error while installing apache-flink 1.11.2

Tags: apache-flink

I tried to install apache-flink 1.11.2 on Mac MacOs Big Sur 11.6, java 1.8.0_311 and received this error:
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Error: apache-flink: Unsupported special dependency :java

Any suggestions will be appreciated. By the way, I really need to install apache-flink 1.11.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not use brew to install Flink -- just do the install directly by downloading the binary release and unpacking it. The [download links are at flink.apache.org](https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html) and [step-by-step installation instructions are in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-stable/docs/try-flink/local_installation/). [Here's the installation guide for Flink 1.11](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/ops/deployment/local.html), though I don't think anything has changed.

FWIW, you'd be better off upgrading to 1.11.6.